# Linq iqueryable What is faster: Accessing table directly or through object hierarchy?

Tags: c#, linq, entity, hierarchy

Let's assume I have 2 related tables:
**Candidates** - has list of **Notifications**
So the question is:

```
Candidates.SelectMany(c=>c.Notifications.Where(...).ToList())
```

or something like

```
var candIds = ...//int array of candidates that i need
Notifications.Where(n=>candId.Contains(n.CandidateId) && ...).ToList()
```

Where performance is better?
And are those expressions are same?

Comment: "Where performance is better?" Why not just try it out? Simply **measure**. Anyway as for nearly every question about performance, you may have a look at [Eric Lipperts Blog](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Your two queries are pseudo code, so they are not the same. It's not even clear how they are related. Couldn't you provide a better example? My recommendation is: let the database do the optimization and don't use `ToList` in the middle of a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your dataset and context, we cannot tell you which one is faster for your scenario.

I would suggest doing your own test scenario :

```
var candIds = ...//int array of candidates that i need
var watch = new Stopwatch(); 
watch.Start();
Candidates.SelectMany(c=>c.Notifications.Where(...).ToList())
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Time Elapsed {0} ms", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
watch.Restart();
Notifications.Where(n=>candId.Contains(n.CandidateId) && ...).ToList();
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Time Elapsed {0} ms", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```